# How to print names in output in python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written python code where i want to print name. Can you please help me to correct this?

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    return None

names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

desired Output:

```
[Ava, Emma, Olivia, Sophia]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert each list into sets then `union` them the result it will be `set` of unique values and convert the result to `list` again.

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
   return list(set(names1).union(set(names2)))

names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"] 
names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"] 
print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

Result:

```
['Olivia', 'Emma', 'Sophia', 'Ava']
```

For more information about `sets` read the following [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it manually: (As I knew how to solve the problem but not familiar to python):

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    newArr = []
        # Iterate in the 1st list 
    for m in names1: 
  
        # Iterate in the 2nd list 
        for n in names2: 
            # if there is a match
            if m == n and len(names2) != 0 : 
                names2.remove(n)
    
    newArr = names1 + names2
    print(newArr)

names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
unique_names(names1, names2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve by removing the duplicate in the list as i learned from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp) 
basically i am adding the names1 and names2 and creating a new dictionary with no repeating names.

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    new_Arr = []   
    new_Arr = list(dict.fromkeys(names1 + names2))
    return new_Arr

names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

and i got the respected out put

Comment: Please add some information how to this code answers the question

Comment: @Sfili_81 i am little bit sloppy on the explaining part if i got it wrong please correct me and thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    l = []
    for elem in names1:
        l.append(elem)
        for elem1 in names2:
            l.append(elem1)
        return sorted(l)
    names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
    names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]

print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.